# Using WinJS on multi-device hybrid app

Tags: html, winjs, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How to use WinJS in the multi-device hybrid template?  Should I have to add references, or can it be done directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already have a Windows Store app, see this blog post:

Porting a Windows Store app using HTML to Cordova

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2014/08/26/porting-a-windows-store-app-using-html-to-cordova.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can just get WinJS libraries from http://try.buildwinjs.com/ or directly from the  example that you can find on the MSFT's site. Just add this in your html

```
<script src="base.min.js"></script>
<script src="ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build WinJS directly from the GitHub repo: [How to build WinJS](https://github.com/winjs/winjs/wiki/Build-WinJS)

And then link in the respective JS/CSS files into your project.